# Access sub folder in secondary email account

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to move emails from the inbox in a secondary Outlook account to a sub-folder in that account.

```
Sub newBox()
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set myInbox = Session.Folders("Secondary").Folders("Inbox")
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Parent.Folders("Complete")

End Sub
```

When I try to set the destination, `myDestFolder`, I get

> Run-Time error, An object could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

You navigated the folder tree from Secondary to Inbox then back to `myInbox.Parent` which is Secondary.

In your answer post you changed to

```
Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("Secondary").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Complete")
```

This indicates the Complete folder is immediately under the Inbox.

```
Sub newBox()

    Dim myInbox As Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Folder

    Set myInbox = Session.Folders("Secondary").Folders("Inbox")
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Complete")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("Secondary").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Complete")
```